# XPath sum function interesting result

Tags: xml, xpath, sum

I have this XML:

```
<a><b>2</b><c>3</c></a>
```

I am wondering why this XPath expression

```
sum(//*)
```

returns 28 and not 5?

Is it because it takes enter symbol at the end (which is 10,13 in assembly)?\

If I write

```
sum(/a/*)
```

I get 5 as intended.

As well if i split the row in different rows (not in one), i get compile error for the sum function.
Like this:

```
<a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
</a>
```

Couldn't find proper answer, why is that?

edit: I am using http://xpatheval.appspot.com/evaluate for testing and learning purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 28 comes from 23 + 2 + 3 because `//*` selects not only `b` and `c` but `a` as well, and `a` has a string value of "23" which converts numerically to the additional 23 that's added to the 2 + 3 that you expected.

When you split contents of `a` such that `b` and `c` are on separate lines, the string value of `a` contains end of line characters that prevent it from being converted to a numeric value as needed by the `sum()` function.

Comment: thanks, this answers my question.
Does sum like that works only if the numbers are in one line? As I've gotten compile error if i moved them to another line

Comment: I've updated the answer to address what happens when you put `b` and `c` on their own lines.